# Arrayformula+VLOOKUP find value of non-empty reference (callback/recursion problem)

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, vlookup

Similar to [An arrayformula to find the previous non-empty cell in another column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88394/an-arrayformula-to-find-the-previous-non-empty-cell-in-another-column).

I have two worksheets like this:

"" = Blank cell
() = Sheet Name

Worksheet One (Form Responses 4) is the input sheet I have values that need to be VLOOKUPed to calculate the value:

```
  Key A | Key B | Value | Value | Value 
  A       A       Med      Med      Med
  A       A       ""      ""     ""
  A       A       ""       ""      "" 
  B       A       Low       Med      High
```

Worksheet 2 (Calculations)
Current Result:

```
  Key A | Key B | Value  
  A       A       9        
  A       A       10      
  A       A       N/A       
  B       A       N/A
```

Expected Result:

```
  Key A | Key B | Value
  A       A       9        
  A       A       9       
  A       A       9        
  B       A       10
```

Third worksheet for as an index for the VLOOKUPs:

Worksheet Three (Data Inputs)

```
   Value | Word 
      1   LLow
      2   Low
      3   Med
      4   MedHi
      5   High
```

In worksheet 2 I have the following formula:

```
==ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A<>"",IF('Form Responses 4'!$B2:$B="",VLOOKUP('Form Responses 4'!B:B,'6. Data Inputs'!B44:C48,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP('Form Responses 4'!C:C,'6. Data Inputs'!B44:C48,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP('Form Responses 4'!D:D,'6. Data Inputs'!B51:C52,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP('Form Responses 4'!B2:B,'6. Data Inputs'!B44:C48,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP('Form Responses 4'!C2:C,'6. Data Inputs'!B44:C48,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP('Form Responses 4'!D2:D,'6. Data Inputs'!B51:C52,2,FALSE)),""))
```

I am trying to reference all the non-blank rows that have the same key and value using and reference back the values. I am using VLOOKUPs in my sheet to reference words from the Google Forms to values. Currently I get the following Values:

```
9
10 
N/A
```

I am unsure how to a perform a callback to reference all the rows that have the same key and are not blank. In my Google Forms I am trying to have them skip a section of the questionnaire if it was previously answered so it will be blank, but unable to get it to call back the initial reference using arrayformula.

Can someone help?

Comment: With Google Forms, form owners/editors are able to let responders to edit their previously submitted answers. Maybe you will save yourself from a lot of headaches if you use this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Formula

`=ArrayFormula({
  'Form Responses 4'!A2:B5,
  MMULT(
    VLOOKUP(
      VLOOKUP(
        ROW(2:5),
        {IF(LEN('Form Responses 4'!C2:C5)>0,ROW(2:5),""),'Form Responses 4'!C2:E5},{2,3,4}),
      {'Data Inputs'!B2:B6,'Data Inputs'!A2:A6},
      2,
      0),
    TRANSPOSE(SIGN(COLUMN('Form Responses 4'!C1:E1))))
})`

### Input (Form Responses 4)

```
   |    A    |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   
---+------------------------------------------  
 1 | Key A    Key B   Value   Value   Value
 2 | A        A       Med     Med     Med
 3 | A        A         
 4 | A        A         
 5 | B        A       Low     Med     High
```

### Word/Value table (Data Input)

```
   |   A   |   B   |
---+----------------
 1 | Value   Word 
 2 |      1  LLow
 3 |      2  Low
 4 |      3  Med
 5 |      4  MedHi
 6 |      5  High
```

### Result (Calculations)

The column titles are manually entered / copy/pasted. The data below them is calculated; the formula is placed on A2.

```
   |    A    |   B   |    C    |   
---+---------------------------  
 1 | Key A    Key B   Row Total
 2 | A        A               9
 3 | A        A               9
 4 | A        A               9
 5 | B        A              10
```

## Explanation

In order to keep the complexity at the lowest level that I thinked that is possible for a one formula solution, I avoided to use open references. Once you understand it, you could decide to refine it or to try other thing.

The above formula includes

1. The solution from my  [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88400/88163) to [An arrayformula to find the previous non-empty cell in another column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/88394/88163) to fill-up the blanks,
2. A VLOOKUP to replace text by their values, taken from the Data Inputs spreadsheet
3. MMULT to make row sums
4. Arrays to put things together.

If you add more rows to the Form Respondes 4 worksheet, then you should update the following references by replacing the `5` on each appearance of them by the number of the last row to include.

```
A2:B5
2:5
C2:E5
```

Comment: Thanks!!! So I kinda follow but i currently get the following error: Error
Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 4. Actual: 1.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for let me know about the error. It's fixed now.

Comment: I still get an error. Once I get it working I will need some time to digest and may ping you to help refine

Comment: @Alex: Check this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/a/rubenrivera.mx/spreadsheets/d/1GAOdpTLH_kSlmuJypHryjkkHIiMSORYKo3hZOaoBK5o/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Alex: Fixed the sharing settings, (i'm using a G Suite account; the default setting is share files only with users from my organization. I always forgot this, I'm sorry)

Comment: Please let me know once you are able to see this sheet. The issue of on SERUM sheet. I think I kind of follow, but what i want to do is just populate the column E https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iH5EeJChF5FisnhJ_SQtL8ORWi4OXh1Rq8DqCZjXXvI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I used the name of the sheets that where included in bode of the question, not in your formula, in other words, you should update the references in the formula to match the sheet names in your spreadsheet.

Comment: @Alex: Also I notice that the file has .xlsx on the title. It's worth to say that the formula in this answer it's very likely that will not work on Excel.

Comment: can you take a look at the sheet I sent over ... I been trying to solve for the last 3-4 days... do you see the problem in what i sent over?

Comment: it will not be used in excel only in google sheets the original document was in excel, but is a google sheet/form now

Comment: @Alex Have you seen the comment that I sent you  4 minutes ago?: `I used the name of the sheets that were included in body of the question, not in your formula, in other words, you should update the references in the formula to match the sheet names in your spreadsheet. `

Comment: Also, bear in mind that that the formula in the answer returns a 5 columns array.

Comment: Yes I am looking to just populate a column just need a 1 column array. I not following: I used the name of the sheets that were included in body of the question, not in your formula, in other words, you should update the references in the formula to match the sheet names in your spreadsheet. Currently, I thought the references work .. although i see it is 5 column array so how do i fix it for what I am trying to do

Comment: Do you follow what I am trying to do based on the sheet i shared with you

Comment: Actually, I'm not spending time in understanding your spreadsheet. Consider to post a new question as a follow up of this one.

Comment: I'm sorry if the previous comment sounds rude. There was people talking to me while I wrote it.

Comment: The question is still inline to this one. I just want to be able to populate the column

Comment: Understood No problem yea i figured you are not rude person :-)

Comment: I just posted a new question as you suggested and gave you thumbs up on this. Thanks below is the new question:  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/105755/problem-iterating-searching-arrayformula-using-previously-defined-non-blank-valu